# Why are my keystrokes hijacked in RDP?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

I am using Windows 7 to remote into Server 2003. Recently the session has started hijacking my keystrokes. When I press "r" the run dialog pops up. Any ideas why this is happening. If I log into the server and try the same keystroke it works fine. If I RDP from XP to Server 2003 it works fine. What is up with Windows 7?

Answer (score 1):

You will find an explanation here:  http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverTS/thread/cbaae74e-8311-4a46-a842-31dcdd6878dc